# Non-vanishing of twists of L functions for GL(4)

Tags: l-functions, automorphic-forms

Hello,

This is a question in the spirit of 
[Nonvanishing of central L-values of quadratic twists?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56542/nonvanishing-of-central-l-values-of-quadratic-twists)
and the application I have in mind is to p-adic L-functions a la Ash-Ginzburg.

The question is this:

Suppose $\pi$ is an irreducible unitary automorphic cuspidal representation of $GL(4)$, say, over ${\mathbb Q}$. Under what conditions on $\pi$, do we know the existence of a finite order $\chi$ such that $L(\frac{1}{2}, \pi \otimes \chi) \ne 0$? Here $L$ is the completed $L$-function.

I know that by a result of Luo from 2005 if $\Re (s ) \ne 1/2$, then there is $\chi$ such that $L(s, \pi \otimes \chi) \ne 0$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I bet this is an open problem.  The issue is that, if $\chi$ has conductor $q$, then the approx. fun. eqn. gives $L(1/2,\pi \otimes \chi)$ as a sum of about $q^2$ terms, and if you average over $\chi$ and $q$ there's an obvious main term, but the error term just barely fails to be manageable (you can succeed on $GL(2)$ and $GL(3)$.)

Comment: David, I agree that the approximate functional equation method has some serious limitations, but let's keep in mind that Luo's result is better than what the naive method gives (he considers some second moments). And that makes me wonder if an $\epsilon$-improvement of the method, with $\epsilon$ possibly very big,  might help deal with $\Re(s)=1/2$.  Also, there are extremely non-trivial results obtained by Bump, Chinta, Friedberg, and Hoffstein (I might be missing some names) that give non-vanishing theorems using completely different methods. Could these results given something for GL(4)?  

Comment: Hey Ramin, if you take a look at the discussion over at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60387 this might apply to the application you're interested in. I don't know much about the $p$-adic $L$-functions for $GL(4)$, but if the Ash–Ginzburg $p$-adic $L$-function is interpolating the values at critical integers (and your central point is critical, like an "even weight" condition for $GL(2)$), then as long as the weight of your automorphic representation is sufficiently regular ($k>2$ for $GL(2)$), the non-vanishing of the $p$-adic $L$-function trivially follows from the non-vanishing of an ...

Comment: (cont'd) $L$-value in the range of convergence of the Euler product. The fact that the $p$-adic $L$-function is a $p$-adic measure will then imply that it has only finitely many zeros and hence there's some twist of the central value which is non-zero. Now, the $p$-adic $L$-functions in Ash–Ginzburg are just for trivial coefficients, i.e. a very small weight, so I imagine this doesn't apply. However, Rob Pollack's answer to the aforementioned mathoverflow question outlines an idea for using higher weight automorphic representations to prove the result for small weights.

Comment: (cont'd) However, this would involve constructing two-variable $p$-adic $L$-functions for $GL(4)$, and knowing something about their $\mu$-invariants, so that would be what they call "difficult".

Comment: Hi Rob, This is very helpful! Thank you. 

Comment: Ramin, I agree that it's not clear whether some tweak might lead to success - Jeff Hoffstein and I tried to do this exact problem once, and got nowhere, but that doesn't mean anything. :)

Comment: By the way, with modern functorialities in hand, there are some very neat GL(4) forms that the Ash-Ginzburg construction applies to - in particular, the symmetric cube of a classical weight $2$ holomorphic form.